# Propriedade ficando nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

Estou enfrentando um problema o qual uma propriedade está ficando `nil` sem explicação.

```
    NSMutableArray * lojas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
for (int x = 0; x < lojaResultado.count; x++) {

            NSDictionary * listaAtributos = [lojaResultado objectAtIndex: x];
            Loja * loja = [[Loja alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray * produtosLista = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [loja     setName: [listAtributos objectForKey: @"Loja"]];
            NSArray * produtosResultado  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [listaAtributos objectForKey: @"Produtos"]];

            for(int y = 0; y < produtosResultado.count; y++){
                NSDictionary * produtoAtributos = [produtosResultado objectAtIndex:y];
                Produto * produto = [[Produto alloc] init];
                [produto                               setNome: [produtoAtributos objectForKey:@"Nome"]];
                getNumber =    [produtoAtributos objectForKey: @"Tipo"];
                [produto                            setTipo: [getNumber intValue]];
                getNumber =    [produtoAtributos objectForKey: @"Tamanho"];
                [produto                          setTamanho: [getNumber intValue]];
                [produtosLista addObject: produto];
            }

            loja.produtos = produtosLista;
            [lojas addObject: loja];
    }
```

Neste momento `[lojas addObject: loja];` a propriedade `loja.produtos` ainda está com a lista, porém depois que vai fazer a segunda "volta" no loop a propriedade `loja.produtos` fica `nil`.

Informações adicionais:

Propriedade na classe:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * list;
```

A variável `getNumber` é do tipo `NSDecimalNumber`.

Versão xCode: 6.1.1

Versão iOS SDK: 8.1

Comment: Quando você adiciona `tires` em `produtosLista`, não deveria adicionar `produto`? De onde vem esse *tires*?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Sim, é `produto` foi um erro no momento que substitui alguns nomes de variáveis para melhor entendimento. Já editei.

Comment: pequena duvida, a propriedade fica mesmo nil ou um array vazio?

Comment: @DaSilva a propriedade mesmo fica `nil`, no momento que adiciono no array ela esta normal ali, em seguida ela ficava `nil`. Encontrei a solução logo abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi este problema utilizando a enumeração rápida e utilizando o conceito **autorelease**, discartando assim o `alloc/init` do array

O código ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
NSMutableArray * lojas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *listaAtributos in lojaResultado) {
    Loja * loja = [[Loja alloc] init];
    [loja setName:[listAtributos objectForKey: @"Loja"]];

    NSMutableArray * produtosLista = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSDictionary * produtoAtributos in [listaAtributos objectForKey: @"Produtos"]){
        Produto * produto = [[Produto alloc] init];
        [produto setNome:[produtoAtributos objectForKey:@"Nome"]];
        [produto setTipo:[[produtoAtributos objectForKey: @"Tipo"] intValue]];
        [produto setTamanho:[[produtoAtributos objectForKey:@"Tamanho"] intValue]];
        [produtosLista addObject:produto];
    }

    [loja setProdutos:produtosLista];
    [lojas addObject: loja];
}
```